# Push messages from one local queue to another remote queue in same queue manager

Tags: ibm-mq

Is there any way of pushing the messages send to one local queue to another remote queue in same qmanager?

```
           Local Host machine
```

Msg->Local Q1->Remote Q2(this is connected to another queue in remote host)

Can this be done with MQ configurations?  Can we avoid coding any utility project?  As this is for transferring messages from one to another queue in same qmanager.

Comment: Do you want a copy of each message to be put to both Q1 and Q2, or do you want a message to only go to Q2?

Comment: I will put message in Q1 then it has to flow to Q2.

Comment: No..  I am using IBM MQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM MQ supports QALIAS objects.

If you start out with the following existing queues:

```
QLOCAl(Q1)
QREMOTE(Q2)
```

To accomplish what you are asking for you can do the following:

```
DELETE QL(Q1)
DEFINE QA(Q1) TARGET(Q2) TARGTYPE(QUEUE)
```

At that point any message put to Q1 will actually be put to Q2.

Comment: Thank you Josh.  I will try this approach.  In this case,  Q1/QA will be treated as local queue? Or it will become remote queue?

Comment: The app can open and put the QA name Q1, and it will resolve to the QR object called Q2.

Comment: Thanks Josh.  Will try this approach and will post the outcome here.

Comment: @JoshMc: if the transfer channel is down, will a put to Q1 fail, or enque and transfer on transfer channel recovery ?

Comment: @Nicholas QREMOTEs will resolve to a Transmission Queue (XMITQ). The message would queue on the XMITQ until the channel recovered and went running again. The put WOULD fail if the XMITQ became full.

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure about your demand. If you want to transfer messages from Q1 to Q2, you can use camel (http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html). It can work as standalone application or be a part of activemq.

Comment: Thank you Mallow.

Comment: Is there anyway of doing this message transfer between MQ's via MQ configurations? I want to avoid developing any utility(java program) for this.

Comment: @user4325796 if you are using activemq, you don't need any java programs with camel. Just config camel's xml file and include that in activemq.xml. Not quite sure about rabbitmq or ibmmq.

Comment: Thanks Mallow,  I am using IBM MQ.